# Javascript Regex plus operator usage

Tags: javascript, regex

So I've read a lot of posts and documentation on the + operator for JS regex, but I'm still unsure of what it wouldo do.

For example, one of the websites I looked after gave the following example:

```
const nums = /\d+/
console.log(nums.test('456'))
```

Says it would look for infinite possibilites for d. But then...

```
const nums = /\d/
console.log(nums.test('456'))
```

... has the same result.

So I tried using numbers... for instance:

```
const nums2 = /45/
const nums 3 = /45+/
console.log(....
```

But testing both regex would STILL give the same result. If I put any numbers before or after 45 with or without the + it will still give me a "true" if 45 is togheter.

So can someone explain what the + symbol in regex means and it's usage in a way I can understand?

Comment: If you only want the test to succeed when the entire string matches the pattern, use the `^` and `$` anchors. For example, `^\d$` will only match a string consisting of a single digit.

Comment: Palestine, this is a JavaScript question, and on how the `+` operator works on regex. I'm not asking about C# or other operators such as `^` and `$`.

Comment: The language is irrelevant here. This applies to the regex rules used in C# as well as JavaScript. The root cause of the confusion here, I believe, is not realizing that a regex pattern can match _part of the string_. That's why you need `^` and `$` if your objective is to test the entire string, which is answered in the linked question.

Comment: It is not called an operator, but a quantifier.  *`+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference in the cases you tried -- if there's one digit, then there's also one or more digit, so they both match.

But if you use it together with other patterns you can have a difference.

```js
console.log(/A\dB/.test("A123B"));
console.log(/A\d+B/.test("A123B"));
```

The first one is `false` because it only matches a single digit between `A` and `B`; the second is `true` because it matches any number of digits.

The difference can also be useful if you use `.match()` instead of `.test()`. This returns the part of the string that matched the regexp, and `\d+` will return the entire number, while `\d` will just return the first digit.

Comment: I see. So instead of using `/A\d\d\d(etc)B/`, I could just use /A\d+B/ ?

Comment: @Rodhis No, because `\d+` will match any number of digits (between 1 and unlimited), unlike `\d\d\d` which will match _exactly_ 3 digits and _only_ 3 digits.